# Log all z-indexes via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, z-index

I have several JavaScript libraries competing for `z-index` supremacy and would like to dump out the complete list of elements by `z-index` without any other properties besides the object type.

Running the following gives me only one element to traverse:

```
$('html').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).css('z-index') + ': ' + $(this).constructor);
});
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You are only selecting one element. Select all the things: `$('*').each(...)`.

Comment: you could try $("*") to get all the elements on a given page.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to look at your CSS file?

Comment: won't `$(this).constructor` always return `jQuery`?

Comment: @Mathletics, I think the `$(this).constructor` as in my example was returning the encompassing `function()...` object, which was also incorrect from me

Comment: "the current `z-index` of each object" That is what `.css()` returns – the computed value. Though that could still be be something like `auto`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$("*").each(function(k, v){
    console.log(v.nodeName + " " + $(v).css("z-Index"));
})
```

Comment: Awarding this as the first complete answer, thanks Richard. I was confused for a while about the .css() being enough information and I think that is the only way to gather the hierarchy, so this solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You are now traversing the `html` element. What you want to do is use the `*` selector to select all elements:

```
$("*").each(function () { 
    ...
```

Comment: @LeonStafford uh, no it doesn't. It returned 969 results when I ran it before this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, that reads the computed styleheets without any third party framework:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll( '*' );

for( var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++ ) {

    var style = window.getComputedStyle( elems[i] );

    console.log( elems[i].nodeName, style.getPropertyValue( 'z-index' ) );

    /* style['z-index'] will also work, but it is better to use the API if there is one, in case something get's changed */
}
```